# How to use RoboVM iOS bindings in LibGDX game?

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

We have a game made with LibGDX already deployed in the Android Play Store and we are now trying to port it to iOS. We can successfully run our game using [RoboVM](https://github.com/mobidevelop/robovm) (mobidevelop fork) but we need some iOS specific code in Obj-C for things like In App Purchases, Ads, Analytics, etc... I've not been able to find much information on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Some of useful links for your requirement

1. For how to implement platform specific code (iOS and Android ads run differently) read this:

   https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code
2. How to implement Admob on iOS read this:

   https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx#ios-setup-robovm
3. Ads, Analytics and many more, roboVM backend (iOS backend) use these:

   https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings
4. You can inject dependency through Robopods and use binding:

   https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods

**EDIT**

Use MobiDevelop's [robovm-robopods](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm-robopods), are high-quality RoboVM code libraries and bindings for the most popular 3rd party services like social media integration, ad networks or crash reporting. Just add a RoboPod dependency to your project and you are ready-to-go!